# What are the advantages of using Chef-server with Vagrant v/s Chef-Solo with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I've done some read-up on Vagrant with Chef-Server v/s Vagrant with Chef-solo and have found blogs talking about the usage of the same. I've failed to find anybody summarizing the advantages of either approach. So, here's my question.

I understand that Vagrant cannot spin up virtual machines on a remote machine. This means running "vagrant up" on a particular machine will spin up VMs on that machine alone.

First of all, is this understanding right?
If yes, what’s the point of using a chef server to provision the server?

I feel that if I’m using Vagrant, using chef solo is the way to go and chef 
server isn’t adding any value.

Do you think I’m missing something?

Comment: Do you want to spin up multiple VMs on a single remote machine or do you want to spin up multiple remote machines?

Comment: I actually would want to spin up on remote machines. But, I read that Vagrant doesn't support this. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is used for spin up VMs and you can provision those VMs with the help of chef recipes or via any other provisioning method. `https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html`

Now, Difference between Chef Server and Chef-Solo:
Chef Server works in Client Server Architecture. You can control or manage all your nodes (VMs launched by Vagrant) with the help of Chef Server. In a particular VM, you can search for other nodes with the help of Chef Server.

Chef-Solo works in Solo mode means, you can provision only single node and you can not get any information about the other nodes. However several techniques exists to overcome such situations like `chef-solo-search`.

Comment: Dheeraj,

First of all, thanks you for your response.
I understand the difference between Chef-Solo and Chef-Server on their own.

My question was: Does using a Vagrant and Chef-Server combination make sense? 
I have this question in mind because Vagrant is spinning up VMs on the machine that I use Vagrant. So, what difference does it make whether I use chef-solo or chef-server?

To summarize, is Vagrant+Chef-Server combination better than Vagrant+Chef-solo combination? and How?